# Can jq select via a filter while retaining the full input context?

Tags: jq

Is there a generic mechanism within jq to select arbitrary elements of a JSON file but return the full structural context of those elements? For example, if I have the following:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "one": true,
    "two": false,
    "three": {
      "hello": "world"
    },
    "four": true
  },
  "bar": [
    1,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "baz": true
}
```

using the filter `.foo,.baz` would normally result in:

```
{
  "one": true,
  "two": false,
  "three": {
    "hello": "world"
  },
  "four": true
}
true
```

but what I'd like is to get:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "one": true,
    "two": false,
    "three": {
      "hello": "world"
    },
    "four": true
  },
  "baz": true
}
```

I can solve that specifically for the given filter using `select`, but I'd like something generic, to be able to run the same code with a different filter and get the same type of result, e.g. running with the filter `.foo.three,.bar[1]` would result in:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "three": {
      "hello": "world"
    }
  },
  "bar": [
    4
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The DSL just doesn't support that, you can't get the desired result with your filter `.foo.three,.bar[1]`. Are you Ok to look for other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give exactly the result you wanted for `.foo.three,.bar[1]` :

```
jq 'def extract(f):
    . as $input |
    reduce path(f) as $path (
    null;
    if ($path | last | type) == "string"
    then setpath($path; $input | getpath($path))
    else setpath(($path|.[:-1]);
                 getpath($path|.[:-1]) +
                [$input | getpath($path)]
                )
    end
    );
extract(.foo.three, .bar[1])' data.json
```

Comment: It's going to take me a couple of hours to decipher all of that, but thank you!

Comment: This gives me the exact solution I was looking for, so I'm going to accept this answer. However, I think @pmf's answer is the one I should have been looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334337/45978

Comment: pmf's solution is nice, but may not be what you wanted due to `null`.

Comment: It's not what I asked for but it is, perhaps, what I _should_ have asked for. My thanks to you both, though; I've learned a lot from reading and understanding both answers.

Comment: Whereas I understand you totally on that, it's hard to understand *why* you *should* have asked for it, because *added data* (null) could cause other problems.

Comment: In my use-case I needed to retain the context that the `null` elements provide, and I should have realized that when I was asking the question initially -- definitely a poor formulation of the original question on my part.

Answer (score 1):

At best you could do an object construction directly by naming the key names under `{..}` and apply a further transformation to get only the desired paths

```
{foo, bar} | .foo |= {three} | .bar |= [.[1]]
```

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Jb10kaAQ_j)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your queries into paths, and the input into a stream, select the pieces matching the query path, and rebuild it to a single output:

```
def extract(f):
  reduce (
    path(f) as $path | tostream
    | select(length > 1 and (.[0] | index($path) == 0))
  ) as $set (
   null;
   setpath($set[0]; $set[1])
);
```

First example using `.foo` and `.baz`:

```sh
jq 'def extract(f): …; extract(.foo, .baz)'
```

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "one": true,
    "two": false,
    "three": {
      "hello": "world"
    },
    "four": true
  },
  "baz": true
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ll-JoNW1M4)

As with sparse arrays though, it'll fill up the missing items with `null`, as otherwise the index wouldn't match anymore. Second example using `.foo.three` and `.bar[1]`:

```sh
jq 'def extract(f): …; extract(.foo.three, .bar[1])'
```

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "three": {
      "hello": "world"
    }
  },
  "bar": [
    null,
    4
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cl2fuvsNwj)

Comment: Addendum: A similar, seemingly simpler approach would be to also employ `fromstream` as in `fromstream(tostream | …)` but it would require to properly adjust the "end-of-array-or-object items" `[<path>]` wrt each maybe interlaced query filter, which tends to be more tedious than just relying on the scalar items `[<path>, <leaf-value>]` which can (more easily) be harnessed to build up the relevant structure using `reduce` and `setpath`. As a consequence, the order of the query filters may be reflected in the output structure (which ideally it shouldn't).

Comment: This is awesome! What does the "length > 1" accomplish? I seem to get the same results with and without it. Is it for some edge case that I just haven't hit on yet?

Comment: Never mind...that's grabbing the last value in the object. I was focusing on the keys and missed that bit in my before/after comparison.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte `length > 1` drops the "end-of-array-or-object items" `[<path>]` (having just one element) and only retains the scalar items `[<path>, <leaf-value>]` (having two elements), as described in my comment above. If you are unfamiliar with streaming in jq, have a look at the [corresponding section](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) in the manual, which is where I have taken the descriptions of `[<path>]` and `[<path>, <leaf-value>]` from.